# How to open multiple JOptionPanes in a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, joptionpane

I am trying to open multiple JOptionPanes at the same time with a for loop, but my code currently opens only 1.

```java
String[] menu = new String[2000];

        for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
            options.add("virus");
        }

        String[] te = toArray(options);

        for(int i = 1; i < menu.length; i++) {

            menu[i] = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "virus", "virus", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, te, null  ); 

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because each option pane is waiting a response before continuing the loop.  You'll need to spawn a thread for each option pane (or a creative SwingUtilities.invokeLater()).